# Issue Creating Kinesis Stream with Scalazon

Tags: scala, amazon-kinesis, scalazon

I'm following the Scalazon example at [here](https://github.com/cloudify/scalazon) to create a Kinesis stream. The following piece of code:

```
val streamListFuture = for {
  s <- Kinesis.streams.list
} yield s
```

gives the following error:

```
[error] KinesisStatsWriter.scala:51: value map is not a member of object io.github.cloudify.scala.aws.kinesis.Requests.ListStreams
[error]       s <- Kinesis.streams.list
```

If I don't use a for comprehension and call `val createStream = Kinesis.streams.list`, there's no error. Can't seem to figure out why.

Similarly, the following bit of code:

```
val createStream = for {
  s <- Kinesis.streams.create(name)
} yield s
```

produces a similar error:

```
[error] KinesisStatsWriter.scala:64: value map is not a member of io.github.cloudify.scala.aws.kinesis.Requests.CreateStream
[error]       s <- Kinesis.streams.create(name)
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author here, the for-comprehension works only if you include the module that implicitly converts requests to `Futures` (it's called `ImplicitExecution`). Try adding the following `import` statement (looks at the sample code in the library README).

```
import io.github.cloudify.scala.aws.kinesis.Client.ImplicitExecution._
```